# Adding JPanels to JFrame wiht it's default layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

Shortly you can just read my codes and see the out put I put it as a picture

```
/*
 * Suppose I have 4 buttons vertically on the right hand side in First PAnel
 * and 4 buttons on bottom horizantally in second Panel
 * and 4 text fiedls in the center in 4 rows in third Panel
 * Using Frame's default border 
 */
       JPanel p1= new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++) {
            right[i]=new JButton("right "+(i+1));
            p1.add(right[i]);
        }
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < down.length; i++) {
            down[i] = new JButton("Down "+(i+1));
            p2.add(down[i]);
        }

        JPanel p3=new JPanel();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<text.length;i++){
            text[i]=new JTextField(30);
            p3.add(text[i]);
        }
        Container c =getContentPane();
        c.add(p1,"East");
        c.add(p2,"South");
        c.add(p3,"Center");
        setSize(300,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
```

The output :
[image]

I want to make it like this 
[image]

Note The second output I used Null layout and setBounds Method

Any Suggestion?

Comment: you may want to take a look at MigLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Create panels for the buttons on the right and bottom - use [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for them. Create another panel  for the labels and text fields and use [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should **always** use one or more layout managers.

The labels and fields would be added to a JPanel with the GridBagLayout.

The first, previous, next, and last buttons would be added to a JPanel with a BoxLayout, LINE_AXIS.  The buttons should be in the order I gave, first, previous, next, and last.  That's what users are used to.

The add, clear, edit, save, and delete buttons would be added to a JPanel with a BoxLayout, PAGE_AXIS. The edit and save buttons should be first, followed by the add, clear, and delete buttons.  I'd put some space between the save and add buttons, as well as between the clear and delete buttons, to visually separate the functions and to minimize the accidental clicking of the delete button.  I'd also put an "Are you sure" dialog on the delete button.

The exit button would be added to a JPanel with a FlowLayout.

The four JPanels would be added to a master JPanel with a GridBagLayout.

The master JPanel would be added to the JFrame.

Edited to add: Here's my code for adding the four JPanels to a master JPanel.

```
protected static final Insets spaceInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 4, 10);

protected JPanel panel;

protected JPanel formPanel;
protected JPanel nextPanel;
protected JPanel editPanel;
protected JPanel exitPanel;

protected void createPartControl() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    int gridy = 0;
    gridy = createPanelLayout(gridy);
}

protected int createPanelLayout(int gridy) {
    addComponent(panel, formPanel, 0, gridy, 1, 1, spaceInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    addComponent(panel, editPanel, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, spaceInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    addComponent(panel, nextPanel, 0, gridy, 1, 1, spaceInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    addComponent(panel, exitPanel, 1, gridy++, 1, 1, spaceInsets,
            GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

    return gridy;
}

protected void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
        int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, 
        Insets insets, int anchor, int fill) {
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
            gridwidth, gridheight, 1.0D, 1.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
    container.add(component, gbc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I get the idea of using many `Layout Managers` but I am having problem with spaces between buttons in BoxLayout can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Sure.  Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(width, height));

Comment: Creates a space between two panel.add statements.

Comment: Thanks again,if I am not bothering you I am in final step adding all panels to master panel,Can you please show me how to  do it it's first time to use `GridBagLayout`